# Laravel-5 Redirect Loop

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-routing

My routes.php like this:

```
Route::get('deneme/{test}', 'TestController@index');

Route::get('send', 'MailController@index');

Route::get('elfinder/tinymce4', 'Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController@showTinyMCE4');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'perm'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){

    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index']);

    Route::resource('kategori', 'Admin\KategoriController');
    Route::resource('icerik', 'Admin\ContentController');

    // Property Routes
    Route::resource('property', 'Admin\PropertyController');
    Route::post("property/lang", ['uses' => 'Admin\PropertyController@langAdd', 'as' => 'admin.property.lang_add']);
    Route::get("property/lang/{id}", ['uses' => 'Admin\PropertyController@langDelete', 'as' => 'admin.property.lang_delete']);

    Route::get('users/add', 'Admin\UsersController@add');
    Route::get('content/add', 'Admin\ContentController@add');

});

Route::get('admin/login',['as' => 'admin.get_login', function(){
    return view("admin.login");
}]);
Route::post('admin/login', ['as' => 'admin.do_login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::get('admin/logout', ['as' => 'admin.logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
```

When I send request to site.dev/admin the browser say:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have delete rotation and leave blank only PHP tag available but this url -site.dev/admin- return same error. I tested 2 browsers, Chrome and Firefox. I think this error stems from browser-cache and installed Opera browser -not installed before- but still get same error.

Comment: Can you show `auth` and `perm` middleware please?

Comment: auth:
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
  if ($this->auth->guest())
  {
   if ($request->ajax())
   {
    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
   }
   else
   {
    return redirect()->guest(route('admin.get_login'));
   }
  }

  return $next($request);
 }

perm:
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
  return $next($request);
 }

Comment: I don't see anything which would be handling a blank route.

Comment: i did debugging with xdebug but from first php code doesn't happened anything. I put breakpoint in public/index.php 22nd line but it's not firing. 
22nd line is first php code in laravel:
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

Comment: Move each of your 3 `admin/*` routes on the bottom to somewhere above the `admin` group and try again.

Comment: Do you have any url rewrite module? Maybe that's where the problem lies. If you are using Apache check the `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: .htaccess rules like these:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. Under the **public** folder exist a folder with name is **admin**. So i changed my rotation like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'perm'], 'prefix' => 'adminpanel'], function(){

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index']);

Route::resource('kategori', 'Admin\KategoriController');
Route::resource('icerik', 'Admin\ContentController');

// Property Routes
Route::resource('property', 'Admin\PropertyController');
Route::post("property/lang", ['uses' => 'Admin\PropertyController@langAdd', 'as' => 'admin.property.lang_add']);
Route::get("property/lang/{id}", ['uses' => 'Admin\PropertyController@langDelete', 'as' => 'admin.property.lang_delete']);

Route::get('users/add', 'Admin\UsersController@add');
Route::get('content/add', 'Admin\ContentController@add');

});
```

And the new url rotation doesn't conflict any folder under the **public** folder.

Good works.